# How to add another class object to the list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have a player class and friend class, player class has friend object in it. But the friend class also has the same fields as player class. how do i add the friendlist to player. Like on facebook where user has friends in his friend list.how to make the commented method in PlayerController class work?

```
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/players", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerReopsitory playerReopsitory;

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public List<Player> getAllPlayers(){
        return playerReopsitory.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
//  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody Player player) {
        playerReopsitory.save(player);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Player getOne(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return playerReopsitory.getOne(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    void deletePlayer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        playerReopsitory.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    Player updatePlayer(@RequestBody Player newPlayer, @PathVariable Long id) {

        return playerReopsitory.findById(id).map(player -> {
            player.setName(newPlayer.getName());
            player.setEmail(newPlayer.getEmail());
            player.setPhone(newPlayer.getPhone());
            return playerReopsitory.save(player);
         }).orElseGet(() -> {
                newPlayer.setId(id);
                return playerReopsitory.save(newPlayer);
            });
        }


//  how to make this function work?
//  @GetMapping("/{id}/friends")
//  public List<Friend> getAllFriendFromList(@PathVariable Long id) {
//      return playerReopsitory.findById(id).get();
//  }
//  

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "user", schema = "rabbit")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Friend {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="playername")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Friend [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", phone="
                + phone + "]";
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "user", schema = "rabbit")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="playername")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    private Friend friend;




    public Friend getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(Friend friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", phone="
                + phone + ", friend=" + friend + "]";
    }
```

```
public interface FriendReopsitory extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

}
```

```
public interface PlayerReopsitory extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {

}
```

```
@Component
public class FriendService {


    private static Map<Friend, Long> getFriends = new HashMap<>();{

    }
}
```

Comment: If a Player has only one Friend field, you can only retrieve one Friend from a Player id. If you want several friends associated with your Player, then the Player class must have a List<Friend> with the associated getters, setters and Spring-JPA mapping annotation.
Are you looking for code improvement suggestion? If friends can also be players, then it would make more sense to have only one class, and if they are not they should extends a parent class, as they are so similar.

Comment: Note that if you have the usual Spring Boot configuration, you can directly say `@PathVariable("id") Player player`.

Comment: friends are also players

Answer (score 0):

As Friends are also players, I suggest you refactor your model to have only one class Player, with a many to many relationship with itself.

```
@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    /*
    * Add other fields
    */

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "player_friends", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PLAYER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "FRIEND_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    })
    private List<Player> friends;

    /*
    * Add other getters and setters
    */

    public List<Player> getFriends() {
        return this.friends;
    }

    /*
    * Implement addFriend and removeFriend methods
    */
}
```

You will then need to deal with collection loading (LAZY or EAGER), add and remove friend methods. But that is not in the scope of this question and you can find plenty of resources online on this topic.